# Setting RowSource/ Control Source to an object in different database in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

Row source for combo boxes and control sources for sub forms require a string. As long as the table being queried by this string is part of the database..things work fine.

But I am trying to query the values for the combos **from a table in a different database**.

*Row source does not accept anything other than a string. How do I set it??*

Also my **subform points to a table in a different database**.. here the object source will also accept nothing but a string.. How do I link it?? (Provide links to examples if possible.)

Answer (score 1):

You can link the tables from the other database, use the IN keyword or use ADO recordsets.

```
SELECT id, atext FROM table1 IN 'z:\docs\test.accdb'
```

To link, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-HA001227658.aspx?CTT=1#BM3